# Problems with 'woocommerce_login_redirect' filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I'm having problems using the 'woocommerce_login_redirect' filter hook. I want the user to be redirected to the front page on login, except for when logging in on the checkout page. No matter what I try the user is still redirected to the front page when logging in on the checkout page. 
Here's my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect'); 
function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout()){
        $redirect_to = 'https://seiltau.no';
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
```

I have tried (is_checkout()==false) and (! is_page('checkout')) as well, but I still get redirected to the frontpage when logging in on the checkout page.

Any ideas?

Comment: when user login from checkout in which page you want to redirect ?

Comment: I don't want to redirect if the user logs in on the checkoutpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace your function's code with follows -

```
if ( $redirect_to == wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ) ){
    return $redirect_to;
}else{
    $redirect_to = 'https://seiltau.no';
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Comment: Adding $redirect_to outside the if-statement still redirects to the frontpage :(

Comment: Is it possible the code inside the filter runs after leaving the current page?

Comment: then i think your is_checkout() function returning false, please check it.

Comment: @Paudun just replace your function code with my above modified code

Answer (score 0):

If someone is searching for a solution to redirect on user role based:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce function for redirecting users on login based on user role
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_my_login_redirect', 10, 2 );
function wc_my_login_redirect( $url, $user ) {
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            $url = admin_url();
        } 
        else if ( in_array( 'seller', $user->roles ) ) {
            $url = site_url( '/dashboard/settings/store/' );
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```